# Can we switch terminals at Heathrow (LHR) for shopping only?

Tags: shopping, lhr

We will be flying into and out of Terminal 5 at Heathrow. Now, my wife has taken fancy to a certain duty-free store located at Terminal 3. Assuming we factor in enough time before boarding our outbound flight from Terminal 5, ***are we allowed to enter Heathrow from Terminal 3, shop and then shuttle over to Terminal 5?***

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Short answer - no, not any more. (It used to be possible pre-9/11, but isn't allowed now)

To change between terminals airside at Heathrow, you need to go through Flight Connections. After the bit where they can issue boarding passes if you don't have one, is the part where they check your boarding pass. No boarding pass for a different terminal, no access to the airside shuttle bus.

Alternately, if you're allowed to enter the UK, you could enter the UK in T5, take the free train connection to T1/T2/T3 and walk the couple of minutes from there to T3. However, you'd then be stuck, as they would want to see a boarding pass before letting you into the security queue, and you won't have a T3 boarding pass, only a T5 one, so they won't let you in.

.

There is a workaround though if you want to do a (significant) amount of shopping. As described in [this FlyerTalk thread](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1186221-duty-free-shopping-transfer-terminals.html) at the end, Heathrow provides a [Personal Shopper service](http://www.worlddutyfree.com/customer-services/personal-shopper.html). If you contact them in advance about it, they can apparently arrange for the item to be brought to another terminal so you can look at it and purchase. Apparently, if you have a lot of time, and it's quiet, they might be able to arrange a transfer, but that part isn't guaranteed.

That looks to be your only way. Well, other than booking a fully refundable (check the T&C closely!) ticket out of T3, follow flight connections to T3 for that, shop, go online and cancel the ticket, ask customer services in T3 to "land" you, follow flight connections back to T5 on your onward boarding pass, then collapse in a heap on your return...!

Comment: what an articulate answer! I'm absolutely impressed and I'll keep your information in mind in case I wanted to shop in a different terminal. However, I thought the shops were the same in all terminals in a given airport. I wonder why this shop is so special...

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. The shop, FYI, is a Chanel boutique, that, according to my wife, stocks hard-to-find items, and of course discounts the duty.

Comment: You need to verify the discounts are really there. Most items are on sale to all passengers - domestic, intra-EU and international. The shops charge the same price to everyone, but can only save on duty for some...

Comment: If you're willing to spend some extra money, you can buy the cheapest flight from T5 :)

Comment: @yo' They aren't keen on people "popping" into T5 then deciding they want to leave rather than fly. Generally they only let you out under escort once an hour, and go via the UK border. Cheapest flights out of T5 are often domestic, and leaving instead of taking one of those is even slower...

Comment: @Gagravarr you can also buy a fully refundable ticket. Or use a fake boarding pass if they do a cursory check.

Comment: @JonathanReez T5 has full-on Conformance, they check your boarding pass is valid, there's still time to make it through to the flight, flight hasn't been cancelled, then mark you as being airside. If you don't get your boarding pass scanned early enough, the system will automatically start offloading you. This is not a system that'll accept a fake boarding pass!

Answer (score 5):

I recently transited through Terminal 2 and I wanted to go shopping. I was offered by the airport staff to transfer me to terminal 3 should I want to go shopping. I didn't take the offer as I was worried about missing my boarding time, but if you do have plenty of time it certainly is possible.

The whole anecdote:

For years and years non BA flights from Asia used to land and depart from LHR terminal 3. However, since last September they switched to the newly refurbished terminal 2. I flew back home from the new terminal a couple of weeks ago (mid November 2014) And yes, I also missed the Chanel boutique at terminal 3. I was offered by the airport staff to transfer me to terminal 3 should I want to go to Chanel shop. I didn't take the offer as I was worried about missing my boarding time, but if you do have plenty of time it certainly is possible.

Comment: Note that only some non-BA flights have moved to T2, others (eg Virgin, Emirates) remain in T3. You need to check the Heathrow website if you're not sure which airlines are in T2 now, and which aren't!

Comment: This answer seems to contrast with the accepted one. Is this because T1-2-3 at LHR are in the same building, whereas the OP was asking for a T5 to T3 transfer? Or is it because the rules have changed? Lastly, is it because you were offered the "personal shopping" service mentioned by @Gagravarr ?

Comment: T1 and T2 are joined, so you can walk freely between them, but it's a bit of a trek. That'll end in not very long when the last airline leaves T1 and they start knocking much of it down. T2 and T3 are near each other, but not joined.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Heathrow airport offers a [personal shopper](http://www.heathrow.com/shops-and-restaurants/services-a-z/personal-shoppers) service.

> Heathrow is delighted to offer you complimentary stylist-trained
>   shopping assistance. Our team members have international knowledge and
>   can offer assistance in many different languages. **If time allows, they
>   may be able to take you to a different terminal to visit a particular
>   store**. Heathrow Personal Shoppers are available by appointment only.
>   Please request an appointment 48 hours before you travel

A review of the service can be seen on [Style Barista](http://www.stylebarista.com/how-to-make-the-most-of-duty-free-shopping-at-heathrow/):

> I was flying out of Terminal 3, and Louis Vuitton only has a boutique
>   in Terminal 5. However, Heathrow’s excellent Personal Shopping Service
>   came to my rescue. Here’s how it works:
>
> 1. Contact the service via their website at least 48 hours before your flight and tell them what you are interested in buying.
> 2. **The service is totally free**.
> 3. A personal shopper will make arrangements to meet you in the terminal and assist you with your shopping, for example by identifying
>      items that may be of interest to you.
>
> If the terminal that you are flying through doesn’t have the boutique
>   that you are interested in, **the personal shopper can take you to
>   another terminal for shopping (note that you need at least three hours
>   to do this)**. Alternately, if you contact the store and pay for the
>   item in advance, the personal shopper may be able to bring the item to
>   you without your having to visit the other terminal.