# Can I change terminals in Heathrow to access airport lounges?

Tags: lhr, lounges

I have a long layover in Heathrow, like 6 hours, and I have a Priority Pass card to access several lounges on terminals 1 and 3. But I will be arriving to T5, and leaving from there as well. Is there any way to change terminals so I can relax at some lounge?

Comment: What are the other details ? Whats your nationality ? Are you flying domestic/international ? Will you have to clear customs ?

Comment: This is NOT a direct duplicate of the shopping question. the shopping question refers ONLY to airside access.  Despite not directly mentioning it, this question is about both airside and potentially non-airside access.

Comment: There are no landside departure lounges in Heathrow. All departure lounges are airside. There are a few landside arrivals lounges, but these are only open in the morning, and only for inbound business class passengers into that terminal (no general Priority Pass)

Comment: @Gagravarr That's incorrect.  As per my answer below, the Air Canada Arrivals Lounge DOES allow Priority Pass access.

Comment: @Doc [Page 6 of the Heathrow Terminal 3 Map](http://www.heathrowairport.com/static/Heathrow/Downloads/PDF/Maps/Heathrow_T3_Map.pdf) shows that the Air Canada lounge wasn't where I thought it was. It is after the exit from customs (turn left), so it's just the Air Canada restrictions that apply

Comment: It would seem to be another question in any case since so much discussion is necessary to figure out if the previous answer applies or not…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As has been pointed out by several people in the comments, your question is similar to the question [Can we switch terminals at Heathrow (LHR) for shopping only?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17709/can-we-switch-terminals-at-heathrow-lhr-for-shopping-only), and indeed that question does give some relevant advice - however there is a little bit more to it in this case.

Priority Pass currently have 4 lounges available at LHR - A ServisAir lounge in each of terminals 1 and 3, the No 1 Heathrow lounge in terminal 3, and the Air Canada Arrivals Lounge in Terminal 3.

The first 3 of these lounges are AIRSIDE, and thus the "shopping" question above will give you your answer - you can not access them from terminal 5.

The last lounge - the Air Canada lounge - is LANDSIDE, and thus presuming you are able to enter the UK (ie, you have a relevant visa and/or do not require a visa) then at first it may appear that you could go through immigrations, and then catch the bus to terminal 3 to access this lounge.

However, unfortunately, that's not the case.  The Air Canada lounge only allows access for Priority Pass customers who are arriving on a flight that arrives into terminal 3.  As you arrived into terminal 5 you will NOT be allowed access this lounge.

So unfortunately, no, you will not be able to access any of the lounges in terminal 1 or 3.