# Going from London Heathrow/LHR T5 (arrivals) to T2 (arrivals)

Tags: london, lhr, british-airways, lounges

I am travelling from USA to London this December (2017).  My British Airways flight will land at London/LHR T5.  I wish to access the premium plaza lounge in T2 arrivals.  I have used this lounge before and quite like it.  How do I go from LHR T5 to T2 (arrivals)?

The [**LHR website only says:**](http://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/getting-around-heathrow/travel-between-terminals)

> "Terminal 2 or Terminal 3 Heathrow Express trains are free for travel
>   between Terminal 5 station and Heathrow Central station (Terminals 2 &
>   3). There's a train every 15 minutes."

But I am not sure if they mean arrivals or departures. What is the best way to get to T2 arrivals from T5 arrivals?

My question is about access to a specific lounge in T2.  [An other question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21946/2236) that is close discusses switching terminals but it ended up being about whether or not the OP may have access to landside.  I do have a valid UK visa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The train stations are not airside so you will need to exit terminal 5 through the immigration control then follow the signs to the station. Fortunately you have the required visa.

Answer (score 4):

Although @mdewey has a good answer, having recently completed my trip, I wish to provide more detail.

If you land in T5 (currently British Airways' hub at LHR), you have to exit T5, go through immigration control, collect your checked bags, go through customs channels and then proceed (~10 min walk) to the Heathrow express train station.  There are signs posted.

As you exit the terminal (after customs), you may also see Heathrow express (train to Paddington station in 15 minutes) tickets being sold.  You will need this ticket if you wish to proceed to London.  If you only are changing between terminals, you do not need a Heathrow express ticket.

Once you proceed to the T5 train station, ensure that you speak with the customer service folks on the platform about any delays before getting into a the train.  Delays were not announced on the train through the PA system.  If you speak with the customer service folks and there is a delay, they may even inform you of alternate routes/buses/tube recommendations.

There will be announcements in English on the train for you to follow and disembark at the terminal of your choice.

The T2 arrivals is a good 12 minute walk once you disembark Heathrow express at T2/3.

Comment: What should you talk to the customer service people _about_?