# Can my mother meet my BF in T5 first class lounge even though she flies to/from T2 & T3?

Tags: lhr, lounges, luxury

I have been trying to look for an answer, but couldn't figure it out. I hope someone can help.

My mother flies into Heathrow on Dec 22nd from Copenhagen (Scandinavian Airlines) to terminal 3. 
She has a 6h layover.
Then she flies from T2 to L.A with Virgin Atlantic.

The same day and during the same hours, my boyfriend will be landing from LA and traveling to Copenhagen- he wants to take her to the T5 BA first class lounge and have a coffee and meet up before Xmas.

Questions is: Is it possible for my mother to take a train from Terminal 2 to Terminal 5 and go through security and meet him?

Comment: Related questions: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21941/can-i-change-terminals-in-heathrow-to-access-airport-lounges?lq=1 and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17709/can-we-switch-terminals-at-heathrow-lhr-for-shopping-only?rq=1 There are some small differences between the questions but generally speaking it does not seem possible to go through security with a boarding pass for another terminal.

Comment: Another possible problem for you - Terminal 2 closed several years ago, and doesn't re-open until June 2014...

Comment: Also, your BF can't guest someone into any BA lounge who doesn't have a same-day OneWorld flight, so even if she could make it to the terminal (which she can't), she wouldn't be allowed in the lounge!

Comment: thanks for ur replies-my BF wrote Heathrow on FB. here's what they say:"Hi,thanks for your post.Your friend can go to T5, provided they have enough time. They will need to follow the flight connection signs when arriving in T3 to T5. At T5 they will go through security before reaching the shopping area. Getting back to T3, they will need to follow the flight connection signs and again go through security back at T3. If they require assistance at the airport our Passenger Ambassadors (in purple uniforms) will be able to help.". As for the lounge, they dont always check the guest's boardingcard.

Comment: This is not a duplicate - it's not just about switching terminals, but also getting into the BA lounge. As Gagravarr has noted, that's not possible if she's flying with Virgin (at least according to the rules). Whenever I've guested someone into the lounge, they've definitely checked both of our boarding cards.