# How to access Heathrow Terminal 3 duty free zone without a plane ticket?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, lhr, duty-free

I'm writing my master thesis on Travel Retail & Duty Free with a specific focus on Heathrow's terminal 3 boutiques. In order to visit this terminal and take pictures for my research paper I already spent some money on a flight to Paris CDG- which unfortunately boards at terminal 4.

**Is there any way I could access the Duty Free zone of Terminal 3 prior to boarding my flight at Terminal 4?**

**If not, how could I access the post-customs Duty Free zone of Terminal 3? Whom should I contact?**

NB: it's solely for research purposes, not to go on a shopping spree.

Comment: Try contacting [World Duty Free](http://www.heathrowairport.com/shop,-eat,-relax-and-enjoy/shops-a_z?category=Duty%20free#World%20Duty%20Free) and ask them for information.

Comment: You should be able to pick up a BA one-way ticket on a short haul flight from T3 for about £50 without too much trouble, maybe even a bit less if you get lucky. Might that be an option? (Do double check the terminals though - something like two thirds of the BA flights from Heathrow go from T5, so you need to ensure you pick a T3 destination!)

Comment: You tried to 'work the system' BEFORE simply asking if you could have access for research purposes?

Answer (score 6):

You have two options: contact World Duty Free, as @JoErNanO indicated in his comment, or contact Heathrow Airport directly.

Heathrow Airport has a section dealing with media and filming: http://mediacentre.heathrow.com/filming_permits - while main focus is on news filming, from that page you can deduce that they entertain non-news filming and photography as well.  From that page:

> For non-news filming or photography, please contact
>   filming@heathrow.com

Answer (score 3):

If you can check-in and pass security more than 2 hours before the flight is due, you could pass through at terminal 4, and use the inter-terminal buses on airside.
I have not used those buses so I am not really sure that you will not have to show that you need to be at the other terminal. But I do know that the buses do run between the terminals, airside.

Added after further reading:

Looking at one of the other questions on this site I would say my suggestion is not going to work: [Can we switch terminals at Heathrow (LHR) for shopping only?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17709/can-we-switch-terminals-at-heathrow-lhr-for-shopping-only) states that you need a boarding pass for a flight leaving from the terminal before you are allowed on the inter-terminal bus.

Comment: I'm not sure that'll work - the inter-terminal buses are on the arrivals side, not departures side, so I don't think a departing passenger will be able to get to them. (They can't in T2 and T5, pretty sure they can't in T4 either but I'm not absolutely certain)